# Angular-CLI build file size differences

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

When build my Angular app, I end up with this out put:

[image]

Looking at this you can immediately see that `0.7f787ebcd865a23bb4ea.chunk.js` and 
`vendor.fbdfd024192bddab02d3.bundle.js` are quite big. I wanted to double check how big they are and looked up the actual file size in the command line and the finder, which is:

- `1.8 MB` for the `0.xxx.chunck.js`
- `1.1 MB` for the `vendor.xxx.bundle.js`

[image]

I thought that it could be the `*.js.map` files, but running the build in prod mode has a rather small difference on the files: [image] 
Can someone explain why I get two different file sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Both of your images show exactly the same sizes, so it's not clear how did you build the bundles the first and the second time.

But regardless of how you built the bundles, to understand why they are so big, you need to know what's inside the bundles. Install Source-MapExplorer and see what's inside.

```
npm install -g source-map-explorer
source-map-explorer 0.xxx.chunck.js
```

Comment: I've added another picture to clarify what I mean. There you can see that the actual size is different.